# Using gunicorn with custom WSGI application

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

I am trying to run a custom `WSGI` with `gunicorn` but the documentation is not clear. I have the following:

```py
from gunicorn.app.base import BaseApplication
from flask import Flask


class CustomApplication(BaseApplication):
    def __init__(self, app, opts=None):
        self.opts = opts or {}
        self.application = app
        super().__init__()

    def init(self, parser, opts, args):
        return super().init(parser, opts, args)

    def load_config(self):
        config = {
            key: value for key, value in self.opts.items()
            if key in self.cfg.settings and value is not None
        }
        for key, value in config.items():
            self.cfg.set(key.lower(), value)

    def load(self):
        return self.application

def run():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    CustomApplication(app, options).run()
```

Is there a way to call this using `gunicorn` utility? Something like `gunicorn 'custom_app:run'` ?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to call this using gunicorn utility? Something like gunicorn 'custom_app:run' ?

Yes, assuming the python file containing your run() function is named 'custom_app.py', the cited command should work as is. If this file is not in the working folder consider using the `--chdir path` option.

https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#chdir

Comment: That does not work